# How to make div next to resizable div change width respectively

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to make the `green` div 'fill' the rest of the area without overlapping with the resizable `red` div. When the `red` div is resize the `green` div should automatically resize as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/wurc57nc/

Is there any simple way of doing this with just the css? Without the need of extra complex js functionality?

I've seen stuff like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6219522/1972457), but I'm after a simpler solution with real-time drag results. Also not after external plugins.

Comment: the green div is resizing automatically here.

Comment: If you add `box-sizing: border-box` to your CSS you can make your `height: 100%` no need for the `calc()`.

Comment: @MrBearAndBeer, what? the green `.right` div is floating.. it is the full width of the body (it is the one that contains the lorem ipsum). What it should be doing is having the text appear in the right of the red `.left` div

Answer (score 1):

If you add `box-sizing: border-box;` to the `.left` and `.right` as well as making `height: 100%;` and adding `width: 80%;` to `.right` you will get the effect you were wanting. The two will not overlap anymore, as you can see both sides of both red and green.

What `box-sizing` does, is tells the website whether to include the padding, or the padding and border, in the defined width. So if you `width` is `80%` in this case, and your `border` is `4px` your `width` is really `100% + 4px`. Adding the `box-sizing: border-box;` includes the `4px` border in the `width`.

CSS:

```
body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%
}

.left {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  border: 2px solid green;
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: no, what I am after is having the `.right` div automatically adjust in width without. If I set it the 80% width to `.right` that renders the resizable functionality of the `.left` div useless...

Comment: No it doesn't serge... You had the width of the `.left` set to `width: 20%;` so you need the `.right` to fill the remaining `80%`. They both will resize together, and they both don't overlap together.

I'd suggest finding a new way to state your issue, because everyone here has given you a solution to the same "wrong" question, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the resize class in CSS(refer sample code), this will handle resizing the divs' for you and also maintains its border color as you resize them,  without using javascript code.

You can also refer my jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/0792rpto/

Sample Code:

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
  <div class="resize left">RED</div>
  <div class="resize right">BLUE</div>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.resize {
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
}

.left {
    border: 2px solid red;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}

.right {
    border: 2px solid green;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: sorry, not sure how this relates to my question at all, I need the `.right` div to automatically fill the width that the `.left` div does not. And resize accordingly.

Comment: @serge: try it on firefox. It worked for me.  As you resize the left div , the right div will occupy the remaining space.