# Resizable side navigation expands when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, resizable

I have tried to follow this solution to create a resizable side navigation bar: [How can I resize a DIV by dragging just ONE side of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219031/how-can-i-resize-a-div-by-dragging-just-one-side-of-it).
I am able to create a resizable div, however, the div also resizes everytime I click to select a menu option. I only want the Sidenav to resize when dragged by a mouse.

One thing to note: Due to the tool I use to develop the site, I cannot use #id, so I have to use a class instead.

Here is the code:

```js
    var i = 0;
    var dragging = false;
    $('.sidenav-wrapper').mousedown(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
           
      dragging = true;
      var main = $('.body')
      var ghostbar = $('<div>',
      {id:'ghostbar',
      css: {
      height: main.outerHeight(),
      top: main.offset().top,
      left: main.offset().left
     }
      }).appendTo('body');
    
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
      ghostbar.css("left", e.pageX + 2);
     });
     });
    
        $(document).mouseup(function(e){
          if (dragging) 
          {
           $('.sidenav-wrapper').css("width", e.pageX + 2);
           $('.main').css("left", e.pageX + 2);
           $('#ghostbar').remove();
           $(document).unbind('mousemove');
           dragging = false;
          }
         });
```

```css
    .sidenav-wrapper 
    { 
    flex: 0 1 auto; 
    resize: horizontal; 
    cursor: e-resize; 
    overflow: auto; 
    width: 300px; 
    margin-left: 8.5%; 
    margin-top: 0px;
    display: block; 
    background-color: #f7f7f7; 
    }
    
     
    #ghostbar
    {
    width:3px; 
    background-color:#000; 
    opacity:0.5; 
    position:absolute; 
    cursor: col-resize; 
    z-index:999
    }
```

```html
<div class="sidenav-wrapper>
        <div class=" sidenav-container ">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li>
                    <a>Menu </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>Menu </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>Menu </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>Menu </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>Menu </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>Menu </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>Menu </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <p> Some content here</p>
    </div>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you try adding your `dragging = true;` to your `mousemove` event? Seems like it might be a better place for it

Comment: @zgood, Unfortunately, I cannot edit or add anything on the actual HTML. The code is generated automatically, including the classes.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you linked, there is a `dragbar` element. You need to add that element to your HTML and perform the mousedown event on that element.

Comment: That would have easily solved the problem. Ufortunately, the sidenav is generated automatically behind the scene. I cannot edit or add anything to it. I have used the `class` I found by inspecting the code, that's why the behaviour. I was wondering if an additional script could be added to prevent the div from resizing when clicked? I have very little JS knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

stop bubbling on the ul to the parent by prevent default. Each time you click, mouse down and mouse up are triggered on the parent element. so, just stop propagating the event at the child.

I mean to say, adding the following lines to the js should stop the sidebar to resize on clicking the ul element.

```
$("ul").on('click',fucntion (e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

PS: i tried running your code on Codepen, it doesn't seem to work, can you add a codepen/jsbin live example which actually works.

Comment: Thanks, Bhavan. Your suggestion stops the div from expanding when clicked, but it also prevents resizing. I also tried `event.preventDefault();` but the result is the same.

Comment: Please put your working code on a codepen or jsbin to help us understand what is happening.

Comment: A lot is built in the background by the tool I use, so it would difficult for me to reproduce the behaviour I am seeing.