# How to make an entire side of a div resizable?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently aware of the resize handle appearing at the bottom right of a div with the css property:

`resizable: horizontal;`

I'm not sure if this a browser only thing but in Firefox, the handle only appears at the bottom-right and only works if we drag that specific portion. If you see any web app, you may see that these apps acheieve the same effect by making an entire side (eg: right) draggable and does not matter if its not on the handle.

To sum up, what I am trying to achieve:

Using vanilla html/css to make an entire side of a div resizable.

For this current case, I cannot use jQuery since this is a React app. Was wondering if this possible through html/css only and not relying on javascript, if not, how do we achieve this in vanilla javascript.

Comment: Does https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize help?

Comment: I checked this out but the problem I am trying to solve here is merely from a user experience perspective. Sure, it works but I am trying to make an entire side resizable, meaninng the user can go on any side and drag to resize rather than just going to the bottom-right resize button.

Comment: try resize:both div {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 20px; 
  width: 300px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

Comment: I don't think you can only achieve it using HTML and CSS. Stackoverflow for example uses a div that receives pointer events and then sets the height of the editor explicitly.

Comment: @GuptaSandeepkumar That didnt seem to work but thanks :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219031/how-can-i-resize-a-div-by-dragging-just-one-side-of-it

Comment: @chingucoding Oh, that sucks. It would be better if the behaviour I was going for was default since that is more obvious (with the indicator still there).

Comment: @GuptaSandeepkumar This works, but not in the way I want :(

Comment: @GuptaSandeepkumar 's linked solution does not seem to work in edge dev build, I can only resize the element using the small arrow at the bottom right, not an entire side.

Comment: why not use a library like React-Resizable?

Answer (score 6):

Would something like this work?
https://codepen.io/rod911/details/wvzPjEV

```
resize.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
   drag = true;
   moveX = e.x;
});

container.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
    moveX = e.x;
       if (drag)
           left.style.width = moveX;
});
```

You need to use js to capture the drag events.

Comment: This is cool! Thanks :) However, I guess it's not possible with html/css alone.

Comment: It works also with Vue 3 with, among others updates in the codepen `<div class="container" @mousemove="containerResizeEventMM" @mouseup="containerResizeEventMU">` and `<div class="left" ref="left">`,`<div class="resize" ref="resize" @mousedown.left.prevent="MiddleResizeEventMD">` and `let REACT= reactive({ drag: false, moveX: undefined})` and `onMounted(() =>{ REACT.moveX = left.value.getBoundingClientRect().width + resize.value.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2; });` and `const containerResizeEventMM= (e) =>{ REACT.moveX = e.x; if (REACT.drag) {  left.value.style.width =` etc `};`