# Set Parent Width equal to Children Total Width using only CSS?

Tags: html, css

I don't know how many `.child` elements `.parent` will contain but I know their individual width.

I want to set the width of `.parent` to be equal to (width of each `.child`) ***** (total number of `.child`)

I don't want to use `floats` and `width: auto`.

Can I do something with `calc()` without using Javascript?

```css
 .parent {
      height: 100%;
      width: calc({number of children} * {width of each child = 100px});
    }
    
    .child {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child">a</div>
      <div class="child">b</div>
      <div class="child">c</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: is using `display:flex` an option?

Comment: are those `child` elements horizontally aligned or are they stacked?

Comment: child items are aside ... side by side?

Comment: `display:inline-block` would do that.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I know this is a bit late, but Hope this will help somebody who is looking for similar solution:

```
<div class="parent" style="display: inline-flex">
            <div class="child" style="display: inline-table">some button</div>
            <div class="child" style="display: inline-table">some button</div>
            <div class="child" style="display: inline-table">some button</div>
            <div class="child" style="display: inline-table">some button</div>
            <div class="child" style="display: inline-table">some button</div>
            <div class="child" style="display: inline-table">some button</div>
            <div class="child" style="display: inline-table">some button</div>
            <div class="child" style="display: inline-table">some button</div>
            <div class="child" style="display: inline-table">some button</div>
            <div class="child" style="display: inline-table">some button</div>
            <div class="child" style="display: inline-table">some button</div>
        </div>
```

the trick is to use `inline-flex` for the `parent` and `inline-table` for the `child`. Everything is dynamic. I make the table scrollable horizontally by adding another `grandparent` with `overflow-x:scroll;`:

```
<div class="grandparent" style="width: 300px; overflow-x: scroll; background: gray">
        <div class="parent" style="display: inline-flex">
            <div class="child" style="display: inline-table">some button</div>
            <div class="child" style="display: inline-table">some button</div>
            <div class="child" style="display: inline-table">some button</div>
            <div class="child" style="display: inline-table">some button</div>
            <div class="child" style="display: inline-table">some button</div>
            <div class="child" style="display: inline-table">some button</div>
            <div class="child" style="display: inline-table">some button</div>
            <div class="child" style="display: inline-table">some button</div>
            <div class="child" style="display: inline-table">some button</div>
            <div class="child" style="display: inline-table">some button</div>
            <div class="child" style="display: inline-table">some button</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks it works great! I need it only for chrome therefore didn't test anywhere else

Comment: Thanks it worked for me with `flex-direction:column`, but as you said `inline-flex` is the trick for this.

Comment: amazing, this works as a direct replacement for display: flex in my case

Comment: Hm, seems like it will break once parent's parent is flex

Answer (score 35):

If you're on Chrome, you can use `max-width: fit-content`

It's [not yet supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=intrinsic-width) by other major browsers though.

**UPDATE:**
As Kasper pointed out in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27382777/set-parent-width-equal-to-children-total-width-using-only-css/52232653?noredirect=1#comment110447229_52232653), most browsers [now do support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=intrinsic-width) `max-width: fit-content` (albeit with a vendor prefix in the case of Firefox)

Comment: With a vendor prefix for Firefox, the situation looks [really good](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_width_fit-content) by now: `max-width: fit-content`, `max-width: -moz-fit-content`

Comment: This should be added to the parent div right? it's not working for me though! @Pranav

Comment: Works now by default in firefox, thus making this seem like the more correct answer as it is the simplest.

Answer (score 11):

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  }

.parent {
  height: 100%;
  display:inline-block;
  background:#bada55;
  font-size:0; /* clear whitespace*/
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border:1px solid red;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The trick here is to set `display: inline-block` to the parent too, not only the children. Worked for me, so I upvoted to cancel out a downvote :-)

Answer (score 10):

use

```
{ width: max-content }
```

on parent node should works fine. It's also an experimental feature.
(I don't know why others do not post this approach. )

Answer (score 3):

You can simply set `display: inline-block;` to the `.parent` element for its width to be equal to the total width taken by its `.child` elements.

```
.parent {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Whichever elements in HTML come with `display: block;` by default, will occupy the full width of their parent element. In your case, the `.parent` element, because of having `display: block;` is taking up the full width of its parent. So, by setting `display: inline-block;` for the `.parent` element will make its width become equal to its contents which in this case is the total width taken by its `.child` elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
* {
      flex-grow: 1;
      flex-basis: 0;
      width: fit-content;
  }
```

you can try this

Comment: If you us * you set this property for all elements....it's not correct

Answer (score -1):

```
.parent{
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
        -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
        flex-basis: 0;
        -webkit-box-flex: 1; 
        -ms-flex-positive: 1;
        flex-grow: 1;
        max-width: 100%;
}

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please provide some explanations with your cod as well.