# Resize element vertically from the top

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am aware of the `resize` property in CSS but it doesn't allow me to specify from which location I can resize the element. Now it's locked to the bottom right.

Instead, I want to be able to resize my element from the top since the element is stuck to the bottom of the viewport.

I am trying to mimick the resize functionality of the terminal in VS Code.
[image: resize vertically]

How can I achieve this result? I'm building my application using VueJS in Electron so ES6 solutions/hints are welcome.

Comment: That's only possible with JS, you could check this SO-Question and Answer for initial directions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960193/how-to-make-html-element-resizable-using-pure-javascript

Comment: This might also be interesting: But webkit-only solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580795/possible-to-style-the-css3-resize-function

Comment: Surely it's a bad idea to resize from the top - unless it is going to overlap the other content or be absolutely positioned to the bottom of something - eg what happens when you make it smaller - are you expecting the whole thing to move up?

Comment: @Pete It is meant to function as a terminal window which can be collapsed. So yes, it will overlap but that's fine!