# Make flexbox sidebar div width increase/decrease via drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox

I have a simple 3 column layout with a left sidebar, content area, and right sidebar. I am using flexbox to handle widths. I would like to make it so that when a user drags the right border of the left sidebar, the div can be resized. I would prefer a css solution if it makes sense but am open to javascript or jquery. Whichever approach is easiest for me to understand : )

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using the css `resize` property (click `Run code snippet` to see the result).

Notes:

- The resize handler is in the bottom right corner of the left sidebar
- The resize property is not yet fully supported by all browser (~74% see [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-resize))
- The styles for the resize handler are still limited (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580795/possible-to-style-the-css3-resize-function))

```css
.container {
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
}

.left-sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: #364F6B;
  color: #fff;
  
  /* This is for resizing */
  overflow: scroll;
  resize: horizontal;
}

.center-aria {
  background-color: #3FC1C9;
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.right-sidebar {
  background-color: #FC5185;
}

.left-sidebar, .right-sidebar, .center-aria {
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-sidebar">
    Left Sidebar - Resize me
  </div>
  
  <div class="center-aria">Center Aria</div>
  
  <div class="right-sidebar">Right Sidebar</div>
</div>
```