# how to change the style of resizing?

Tags: html, css

I really don't like the resize propery of css3. Is there any way to change that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to style the css3 resize function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580795/possible-to-style-the-css3-resize-function)

Comment: @edison xue please accept the answer if the solution I posted works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no default way to do this in css. However jQuery UI offers a solution if you use their [resizable](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-handles) function. The `e` and `w` stands for `east` and `west`.

```
divElement.resizable({
    handles: 'e, w'
});​
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/bx2mk/