# Is it possible to use the `resize` CSS property on the HTML `body` element?

Tags: html, css

[My website](https://fanaro.io) has a fixed `max-width` which I would like to improve upon by also enabling the user with a draggable border on the sides, so she could read on whatever width she desires. Most recommendations online seem to go through some — hideous — mess with JS to get this simple effect going; thankfully, CSS now seems to feature this by default by now. However, I can't seem to make it work for the `body` element. Am I doing it wrong or `body` just can't receive this property?

The example below is hopefully minimal, if there are any mistakes, please do point them out:

```css
body {
  /* Preparation of the example design */
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  max-width: 90vw;

  /* Resize Properties */
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden; /* this depends on what you want to experiment with */
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <p>This is a very long text
 al;djf;alskdjf;laskdjf;asldkjf;alsdkjfl;asdjf;lasdkjf;lasdjf;lasjdfl;asjdl;fajsdl;fja;ldfjl;jadf</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `overflow` to `html` to disable the overflow propagation:

```css
body {
  /* Preparation of the example design */
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  max-width: 90vw;

  /* Resize Properties */
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden; /* this depends on what you want to experiment with */
  border: 1px solid green;
}

html {
  overflow: auto; /* anything different from visible */
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <p>This is a very long text
 al;djf;alskdjf;laskdjf;asldkjf;alsdkjfl;asdjf;lasdkjf;lasdjf;lasjdfl;asjdl;fajsdl;fja;ldfjl;jadf</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

> UAs must apply the `overflow-*` values set on the root element to the viewport. However, when the root element is an `[HTML]` html element (including XML syntax for HTML) whose overflow value is visible (in both axes), and that element has a body element as a child, user agents must instead apply the `overflow-*` values of the first such child element to the viewport. The element from which the value is propagated must then have a used overflow value of visible. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/#overflow-propagation)</sup>

Comment: Cool, your answer does seem to work indeed with the snippet run in SO. However, could I ask you for something extra, please? I'm trying to incorporate this into my website but it doesn't seem to work. I simply added the `resize` and `overflow`, but it doesn't seem to work. Perhaps my example wasn't as minimal as it should.

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro did you add the overflow to html? maybe it's a cache issue?

Comment: Yes, I did also add `overflow` to `html`. I don't think it's a cache issue, I've tried with at least 2 browsers while rerunning everything &mdash; it doesn't allow scrolling the page with the mouse wheel anymore either. If you would be so kind as to examine [the CSS](https://github.com/FanaroEngineering/fanaro.io/blob/master/index.css) a bit :[] . I've tried to also automate the build process, I usually use `bash tools/build_watch.sh` to run and build everything. Anyway, thanks so far.

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro I am looking at the site: https://fanaro.io/ and I don't see overflow applied to the html element

Comment: It wasn't applied because I was experimenting with it locally. I thought you were going to clone the project and try to also experiment with it. Anyway, I've added it to the project now, it should be live when Github Pages updates it.

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro the issue is the display:table applied to html, you should not mess with the display of html. remove both display you added to html and body, I don't see them useful, keep the default display for both of them

Comment: I think I was using the `display: table` stuff to ensure the centering of the `body`, I don't really remember. It seems to work without it at first glance, I'll check if nothing is broken and then accept your answer probably. Thank you again for the help so far.

Comment: One last thing, if you don't mind: do you know a reference as to how to style this styling mechanism? &mdash; having it only at the very end of posts seems weird and counter-intuitive. So far the closest I've got is [this 2013 answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18594432/4756173).

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro you have to consider JS or some plugin for this. There is no native and robust CSS solution fo this

Comment: So you don't think it's even worthwhile to ask a question on `resize` styling here then? Not even to get a more updated version of the answer I mentioned?