# How to allow text-area resize on the whole border?

Tags: html, css, drag-and-drop, resize, textarea

I have a text-area that I can resize horizontally. The issue is that I can only do it by grabbing the bottom right corner of the text area.

Is it possible to allow the resizing by grabbing any point on the right border? Bonus point: can I also change the resize logo with a custom one placed in the middle of the right border?

Here is the code:

```css
textarea{
  resize: horizontal;
  border:0;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<textarea>
At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. They offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.
</textarea>
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580795/possible-to-style-the-css3-resize-function

Comment: This is not a duplicate. This link is about restyling the grabbing cursor. I'm talking about allowing the user to resize the textarea by grabbing ANY point of the border.

Answer (score 0):

```
textarea::-webkit-resizer {
  border-width: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent orangered orangered transparent;
}
```

yes you can change the resize logo. just simply put this code.

Comment: I'm primarily looking to resize te textarea by grabbing any point of the right border. Regarding the resize icon, I wanted to place it at the center of the border.