# How can I create a DIV element that is re-sizable by mouse drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning HTML5 and Bootstrap, I have my parent container(fluid) inside which I have 3 div, I always use the code of bootstrap class(col-md/xs/sm/lg) to show how the UI should be for different view-portal 
but how can I dynamically re-size these div using mouse drag over its borders? I mean like enlarging a image.

Also by increasing one div size the other two should dynamically re-size themselves within the container.

Is there any JS code which I can download? is there any thing to learn that might help me?

Comment: You have to show you've tried to figure out what you're wanting to do. There are likely plenty of different ways to do this.

Comment: for resizing the div you have to create the border of the div using div element and apply drag on the border div elements and increase the widh and height according to that

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673348/emulating-frame-resize-behavior-with-divs-using-jquery-without-using-jquery-ui/4673568#4673568

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try [Resizable](http://rightjs.org/ui/resizable/demo) component of RightJS UI if you want it to work out of the box.

After all, custom implementation in pure JavaScript is fairly simple: [How to make HTML element resizable using pure javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960193/how-to-make-html-element-resizable-using-pure-javascript)