# What's the cleanest way to make a resizable three-column layout?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Sorry if the title isn't descriptive, but I'm working on a web-based application in javascript using the HTML5 canvas. I want the page to adjust to the window size, but I also want the columns to be resizable - that is, you can drag the vertical lines to change their width. The thing is, the canvas width and height attributes must be in pixels (setting the CSS properties stretches the image instead of widening the drawing surface). I need to change the canvas attributes through javascript. I have trouble working with all of these constraints together.

[image: Disposition example]

I tried Making the templates-panel float left and the properties-panel float right, but it ends up below the canvas and above the status-bar everytime. I've also got the status bar set to `position:fixed` but it tends to go above the canvas a bit. How would you do it? Keep in mind I have to be able to resize the window or the panels individually (except the menubar and status bar which never change size).

EDIT: quick edit to add that I can't use JQuery / JQuery-UI. The application is quite computer-intensive, so I had to get rid of it. My compatibility target is IE9 anyway.

Comment: I think you're going to have to use Javascript to make your panels re-sizable, the only CSS property that I know of that will let you do this, `resize` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize, is not supported in IE9.

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick google search on how to do this and found a stack overflow post with a similar answer, here is the fiddle that was provided, here is the javascript portion:

```
var i = 0;
   $('#dragbar').mousedown(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        $('#mousestatus').html("mousedown" + i++);
        $(document).mousemove(function(e){
          $('#position').html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
          $('#sidebar').css("width",e.pageX+2);
          $('#main').css("left",e.pageX+2);
       })
       console.log("leaving mouseDown");
    });
   $(document).mouseup(function(e){
       $('#clickevent').html('in another mouseUp event' + i++);
       $(document).unbind('mousemove');
       });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Bek9L/

And here is the post:

[Emulating frame-resize behavior with divs using jQuery without using jQuery UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673348/emulating-frame-resize-behavior-with-divs-using-jquery-without-using-jquery-ui)

The fiddle uses jQuery but not jQuery UI,

You will need to use percentages for width, look into responsive design.

http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design/

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the article about responsive design, looks interesting. I'll look into it. The fiddle you linked though is JQuery based and uses "ids" everywhere for a two-column layout. Adding one column to it breaks it all, or I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: No problem. Also codeschool.com offers an awesome course for responsive design called "Journey into mobile", you can get a free 2 days by googling "codeschool hallpass" and take it, it will be well worth the time!

Comment: Yeah, fighting with floats is a pain. I managed to get as far as [this](http://jsfiddle.net/zon2uym1/6/) by adapting the code from a couple of answers, but I think I'm just going to switch to using a table - the behavior will be much more predictable and I don't want a "responsive" design where columns might fall below the app.

Answer (score 0):

it's this are you looking for?
[fiddle link](http://www.jsfiddle.net/htbdbut5/1/)

```
<style>
/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }


/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.group:after {
    clear:both;
}
.group {
    zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */
}

/*  GRID OF THREE  */
.span_3_of_3 {
    width: 100%;
}
.span_2_of_3 {
    width: 66.1%;
}
.span_1_of_3 {
    width: 32.2%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .col { margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;}
    .span_3_of_3, .span_2_of_3, .span_1_of_3 { width: 100%; }
}
</style>
    <div class="section group">
                    <div class="col span_1_of_3" style="background-color:red;color:white;text-align:center;">
                    template
                    </div>
                    <div class="col span_1_of_3" style="background-color:blue;color:white;text-align:center;">
                    canvas
                    </div>
                    <div class="col span_1_of_3" style="background-color:gray;color:white;text-align:center;">
                    properties
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me that :after clearfix, I might use that someday. I ended up working in the fiddle so much it isn't the same thing at all, but here's what I ended up with: http://jsfiddle.net/htbdbut5/2/

Comment: very good... you should go to  http://www.responsivegridsystem.com 
there you can find an easy way to get responsive divs

Comment: I don't want that. I'm making a desktop-style application, columns should never go to below the canvas and you should never have to scroll down.